# Proving half of if and only if for separating seminorms

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove that if a separating family of seminorms $D = \{\sigma_{\lambda}\}$ has a finite supremum for each $\lambda$ on $X$, then the map $f: x \mapsto \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \sigma_{\lambda}$ is a norm on $X$.

I've nearly done so by proving all of the norm axioms for $\sigma$, however I'm stuck on proving that $x = 0 \implies \sigma(x) = 0$. The opposite direction is quite simple as it follows directly from the definition of a family of separating norms, but I cannot see why $x = 0$ *must* imply that each seminorm in my family is also equal to $0$. What is restricting some member of my family of seminorms from having a value $\neq 0$ for $x = 0$? To me, it doesn't look to really be any result from the definition.

For clarity, my given definition of separating is that for each $x \neq 0$ in $X$, there exists $\lambda \in \Lambda$ such that $\sigma_{\lambda}(x) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $s$ is a semi norm, then, **by definition** we have $s(0) = 0$. The difference
between norm and semi norm is that a semi norm may be zero for non zero argument.

Since $\sigma_\lambda(0) = 0$ for all $\lambda$ we have $f(0) = \sup_\lambda  \sigma_\lambda(0) = 0$.

Comment: Is it explicit in the definition of separability however that $x = 0 \implies \sigma_{\lambda}(x) = 0$? That is what doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: Ohh, nevermind I understand after your edit. Thanks!

Comment: @frobe: It has nothing to do with separability. It is because it is a semi norm.

Comment: Strange, my definition of seminorm has that it must be $\geq 0$ for all $x$, and then simply $f(kx) = |k|f(x)$ and the triangle inequality... no mention of $f(0) = 0$ (I see why that makes sense though).

Comment: It follows from positive homogeneity since $f(0) = f(0\cdot x) = 0 f(x) = 0$. (So my comment about definition in my answer is not quite correct!)